# Database file is locked

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlite

the program on which I am working gets data from a web service, adds data to database,delete and update.
But sometimes when i run my application all the actions are successful but sometimes when i want to add,delete or update data I get this error.

> Server was unable to process request. ---> The database file is locked
>   database is locked

I cant understand the same program at some time works fine but at some time the very program gives this message.

Comment: What database engine are you using? Have you checked the database logs?

Comment: which database are you connecting to? MS Access .mdb file or SQL Server? Can you also show the connection string?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail about which database you're using and how you're accessing it.

Comment: this basically happens when a file is being used up by another operation. What kind of DB are you using and what kind of application do you have in place, is it Asp.net or windows form or WPF

Comment: I am using sqLite databse. My app interacts with a web service. The web service contains an sqLite database file. Db file is located in the App_data folder.

Comment: string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string;
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection();
            sql_con.ConnectionString = "Data Source="+path+"\\user.s3db;;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";In the web service this is my connection string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SqlLite doesn't allow two threads to use the database at the same time.

The easiest way to solve it is to use the `lock` statement around all database calls.

Comment: but the issue is that I have 4 such databases on my website all other apps related to them are working well but only this app is not working with the web service. Not working means sometimes it work and sometime the same app give the error as  I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried to load test your other sites? They will run into the problem sooner or later. You are maybe trying to use multiple db connections for the same HTTP request in the webservice?

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent package called SysInternals. one of the component inside is Process Monitor (procmon). Use it on order to check which application locking your database files and if 2 instances of your application are "fighting" about getting lock on the DB files.

In Sqlite multiple processes can read from the DB files, but only one is allowed to make changes (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) at certain time. if more than one process is trying to change the DB in the same time you'll get this error. you can use Mutex to sync between the processes  accessing the DB.

BTW, sqlite documentation recommends to avoid using the database from multiple threads. in order to make sure only one thread will access the DB at the same time, you can create a static class that will do all the interaction with the database and use a lock statements inside this class to avoid accessing the DB from multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use file based database like Access?

Database file always locked (in almost all database system), please try stop database service to unlock the file.

Comment: I am using sqLite database file. How a web service can do that means stopping the file to unlock?